# Entity Framework returns null object when row has null values

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4.3

I have an existing database (**which I cannot modify in any way**) that I'd like to use EF to code against. There are no primary keys, foreign keys or actual relationships between tables - everything seems to be handled by applications using the DB.  For most of the tables/entities, this has been trivial. However, I've got one class, like the one below (simplified) that I'm struggeling with.

```
[Table("tableName")]
public class MyClass
{
    [Key]
    [Column("id")]
    public int? Id { get; set; }

    [Column("name")]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    [Column("address")]
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

Things like `_context.MyClasses.Where(x => x.Address == "something")` work fine. However, it seems that when the id column is NULL in the DB, i get a null object back - even though CompanyName and Address have values. And I need those values, regardless of whether id (or whatever else) is null. Is there some way to force EF to generate the objects and ignore empty columns?

Removing or movin the [Key] attribute gives me an exception like "Must have a key column" (and the Id-column is also used to map a collection of other classes into this one if there are any that match).

**UPDATE** Don't think about the Id-column as an actual identifier. It's basically just an integer with a stupid name.

Comment: how can a PK be null ... not by technical option, but by usage ...

Comment: It's not really a PK in the DB, it just seems to have to be marked as Key in the entity for it to be able to collect some other entities into it...

Comment: btw for "Must have a key column" exists a workaround: just mark all columns as key (like EF does it with ambigous views), or add a new column (auto inc)

Comment: You are out of luck if I'd can be null. You need a non null key for EF. If name and address are unique and non null you could make that your PK for EF...

Comment: such a database is not a good candidate for an OR/M as EF and neither NH, maybe you can have some satisfation by using dapper dot net  instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## **The solution**

Like Andreas Niedermair commented on my question, I've now added [Key] to multiple columns in the database. I found that four columns together as a composite key is always unique in this case.

Since I'm never inserting new content to the database, this seems like a decent solution in this edge case scenario, I guess.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot put a KeyAttribute above Id property if it is nullable in your database. That's what's causing you the problems...

The primary keys cannot be nullable, but I guess you know that...

Comment: That seems reasonable, but why does EF throw an exception if I remove it? As mentioned, there's no actual PK in the database.

Comment: @ArveSystad, No, it isn't reasonable. Consider a log table where there is no unique key at all (you *may* have it but that's often not needed). Does that mean you can't query such a table with EF?

Answer (score 2):

You must have a `Key` column and that column must contain values for this to work. Marking a column as `Key` indicates that this is the Primary Key column for that table.

If the `Key` column contains a null value then that row won't be returned to the client. If the `Id` column isn't the primary key (as it can contain a null value) then you need to add a new column that can act as the primary key.

Comment: But then - why can't i remove the Key-attribute without getting an exception back? I've got other similar tables which has no key (neither in DB nor model).

Comment: @ArveSystad - because you need a `Key` column.

Comment: I've got another class/table which works perfectly fine without one, so I cannot really see why...

Comment: ..nevermind what I said. The other entity ofcourse uses the EntityNameId convention to get its key.

Comment: Seems like the solution will be either to make the responsible ones change the DB, or to write SQL manually. :-(

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a Key column. EF requires you to have one. For your purposes, though, you can use an alternative way:

Set your Id's StoreGeneratedPattern property as Identity, and leave its generation and management to EF. Do not use Id for your nullable purposes; create another column like MyId, which is Nullable and not EntityKey, and use it any way you want.

Comment: How/Where do i set the StoreGeneratedPattern property? It seems to be a Model designer-thing, and I do not have an edmx-file.

Comment: I believe you can put StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" attribute on top of the model definition, though I'm not sure